# Cost function in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
def h(theta,X):
    return np.dot(X,theta)

def computeCost(mytheta,X,y):
    return float((1/2*m) * np.dot((h(mytheta,X)-y).T,(h(mytheta,X)-y)))
```

this is a cost function and I was wondering why I need to transpose the first h(theta, X)

Comment: It looks like he's using `np.dot` to calculate sum-of-squares.

Comment: You're defining `h()` yourself, so if you want the arguments to be `X, theta`, then you go right ahead and change it.  Just remember to also change all the calls to it.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment I try to give an answer upon my assumptions. I am not sure about the data structure of you input variables theta and X and your output.

Numpy dot products documentation states:

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b

The matrix multiplication is defined from R(lxm) x R(mxn) -> R(lxn)
Note that the number of columns of one matrix have to equal the number of rows of the other.

That means if you have two row-vectors x,y possible results are:

- dot(x.T,y) => Scalar
- dot(x,y.T) => Matrix

The option dot(x,y) does not exist, as the matrix-product is not defined for this case, because the number of rows of x cannot equal the number of columns of y.
For the case of a row-vector x and a Matrix Y you may get:

- dot(Y,x) => column-vector
- dot(x,Y) => row-vector